# Generate a makefile to include in the deliverable

Tags: makefile, automake, generic-programming

I have a problem.
I am currently working on a linux application (let's call it BigApp in this scenario). This application needs to be customizable via shared objects(so) and ini/text files.

The prerequisites for creating such shared objects are:

1. Generating a C file in a custom location (done from code)
2. an additional h file from the source repository of BigApp (done via makefile)
3. an executable shell script in the application bin folder (done), which sets up some parameters, calls the internal c file generator described above at number 1, and calls some kind of build script described below.
4. "the" build script which should compile the h file and the generated C file into a shared object.

The problem I have here is that once BigApp is installed, step 3 (compiling a new shared object) should be done by anyone with some basic linux-like skills. Also, the build script at number 4 should somehow use the same settings which were used when compiling and installing BigApp.

BigApp uses automake (makefile.am, configure.ac files for root and subfolders).
I assume I need a Makefile.am template to generate a particular makefile for the shared object when running configure on the BigApp, but I have no idea how to do this while avoiding it being run when I "make" the BigApp.

I could use any kind of suggestions or references to a tutorial.
Thank you!

EDIT: at the time, the build script for the shared library/object is a small shell script which simply calls gcc two times, but with no particular platform settings, and no relation to the BigApp makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since you posted this question but what you should do is turn your current makefile for your shared libraries into a Makefile.in (or even write a Makefile.am using Automake) that gets completed by your configure script (created using Autoconf) for BigApp. You should study the GNU Build system manuals.